# Can a Monk replace Elemental Attunement when learning new Elemental Disciplines?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

When the Way of the Four Elements learns new Elemental Disciplines at 6/11/17, you're able to replace an elemental discipline you already know with a different one.

Is it possible to retrain the Elemental Attunement discipline that you get as a default discipline, or is it only the ones you choose to learn? Aside from roleplay concerns (which is nice from time to time) it's kind of useless and I'd rather pick up another ability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Whenever you learn a new elemental discipline, you can also replace on elemental discipline that you already know with a different discipline (PHB 80).

That looks like an unequivocal yes to me.

You *are* limited to one per new elemental discipline, so you can't start from scratch if you're level 17, but you can replace one of your L1 disciplines at L6, one of your L1s or your L6 one at L11 and either of the L1s, L6 or L11 at L17.

So if you, say, wanted two disciplines that require L6 at L6, you could swap out a L1 and grab two L6 abilities.